# Parsing JSON output from Juniper switch using Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath, juniper

I have this JSON output from Juniper switch where I need to get the remote system name associated with  `lldp_local_parent_interface_name` having the value `ae0`.
So, I only know the value `ae0` and I need to get the remote system name `A_B_C_D` in order to start targeting this host to execute some other tasks.

The data, inside the file *juniper-data.json* looks like this:

```json
{
    "output": {
        "lldp_neighbors_information": [{
            "lldp_neighbor_information": [{
                    "lldp_local_parent_interface_name": [{
                        "data": "ae0"
                    }],
                    "lldp_local_port_id": [{
                        "data": "xe_0/2/0"
                    }],
                    "lldp_remote_chassis_id": [{
                        "data": "00:00:00:00:00:00:00"
                    }],
                    "lldp_remote_chassis_id_subtype": [{
                        "data": "Mac address"
                    }],
                    "lldp_remote_port_description": [{
                        "data": "xe_1/0/1"
                    }],
                    "lldp_remote_system_name": [{
                        "data": "A_B_C_D"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "lldp_local_parent_interface_name": [{
                        "data": "_"
                    }],
                    "lldp_local_port_id": [{
                        "data": "ge_0/0/23"
                    }],
                    "lldp_remote_chassis_id": [{
                        "data": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
                    }],
                    "lldp_remote_chassis_id_subtype": [{
                        "data": "Mac address"
                    }],
                    "lldp_remote_port_description": [{
                        "data": "bond0"
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }

}
```

Here are my tasks:

```yaml
- name: load data to var
  set_fact: 
    remote_sys_name: "{{ lookup('file', 'juniper-data.json') | from_json }}" 
- name: view loaded data
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ remote_sys_name | community.general.json_query('output.lldp_neighbors_information[0].lldp_neighbor_information[*].[?lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data=='ae0'].lldp_remote_system_name[0].data') }}"
```

Expected results

```yaml
"item": "A_B_C_D"
```

What I got is

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'ae0'. String: {{ remote_sys_name | community.general.json_query('output.lldp_neighbors_information[0].lldp_neighbor_information[*].[?lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data=='ae0'].lldp_remote_system_name[0].data') }}"}

Comment: About as ugly as the json data structure spitted out by the juniper device... => `{{ output.lldp_neighbors_information | map(attribute='lldp_neighbor_information') | flatten | selectattr('lldp_local_parent_interface_name', 'contains', {'data': 'ae0'}) | map(attribute='lldp_remote_system_name')| flatten | map(attribute='data') }}` <= this gives a list of stings of the found names.

Comment: IMO this won't get really nicer with `json_query`. If you know a bit of python, [this answer about using a custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72752544/9401096) might give you some alternate ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not care about the exact hierarchy of nodes and their names beside `lldp_neighbor_information`, you can use a cohort of [object projections](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#object-projections) and [flatten projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections) to simplify it:

```
*.*[][].*[][?
  lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data == 'ae0'
][].lldp_remote_system_name[].data
```

As for your current attempt, the issue lies in the fact that your condition is wrongly located in this bit:

```
lldp_neighbor_information[*].[?lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data=='ae0']
```

The condition should actual replace the star:

```
lldp_neighbor_information[?lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data=='ae0']
```

Ending up with the query:

```
output
  .lldp_neighbors_information[0]
  .lldp_neighbor_information[?
    lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data=='ae0'
  ]
  .lldp_remote_system_name[0]
  .data
```

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: item
  loop: >-
      {{
        lookup('file', 'juniper-data.json')
        | from_json
        | json_query('
          output
            .lldp_neighbors_information[0]
            .lldp_neighbor_information[?
              lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data==`ae0`
            ]
            .lldp_remote_system_name[0]
            .data
        ')
      }}
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=A_B_C_D) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: A_B_C_D
```

---

**Bonus:** If know you before hand that you will only have one element, you can also end your query with `| [0]` to [stop the projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions) and only get the first element.
This way, you can get rid of the loop:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: remote_sys_name
  vars:
    remote_sys_name: >-
      {{
        lookup('file', 'juniper-data.json')
        | from_json
        | json_query('
          output
            .lldp_neighbors_information[0]
            .lldp_neighbor_information[?
              lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0].data==`ae0`
            ]
            .lldp_remote_system_name[0]
            .data | [0]
        ')
      }}
```

Does yields the name right away:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  remote_sys_name: A_B_C_D
```

---

**Bonus bis:** if your *interface name* is in a variable, here would be the task. Mind that it is in a variable local to the task here, but you might define it in any place your requirements call for.

```yaml
- debug:
    var: remote_sys_name
  vars:
    _interface_name: ae0
    remote_sys_name: >-
      {{
        lookup('file', 'juniper-data.json')
        | from_json
        | json_query('
          output
            .lldp_neighbors_information[0]
            .lldp_neighbor_information[?
              lldp_local_parent_interface_name[0]
              .data==`' ~ _interface_name ~ '`
            ]
            .lldp_remote_system_name[0]
            .data | [0]
        ')
      }}
```

Comment: this works great Thanks, I would like one more bonus, now how I can provide the ae0 as a var

Comment: @DarkOne00X _bonus bis_ added in an edition of the answer.